# Can we create temporary hash from ipfs permanent hash?

Tags: javascript, python, ipfs

I am experimenting with ipfs these days and I know that in ipfs instead of using an location address, IPFS uses a representation of the content itself to address the content. This is done using a cryptographic hash on a file and that is used as the address. The hash represents a root object and other objects can be found in its path. So, now I want to replace the ipfs hash with some temporary hash. But i have no idea about this. So if anyone know how to do that please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, you should clarify it.

1) **If you want to compute a hash representing an immutable file that will no longer represent it after a while, it is impossible by design**. The hash is a representation of the content of the file. There can be only one hash for any particular sequence of bits. (BTW, that what guarantees deduplication.)

2) **If you want to give a hash that will give access to a file only for a given time**, this is probably possible: use [IPNS](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/concepts/ipns/), or [DNSLink](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/concepts/dnslink/). 
Both work like a domain name: if you create it, you have control over where it redirects. You can use it to redirect to your file in the beginning and then redirect to an invalid hash or an "error page" object you crafted. 
Find help and code [here for javascript](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs#name).